# Why needs manual refresh for users having role other than administrator role

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, xrm

I have two users one AA with role administrator and other BB with role Other than administrator.

DONE following test on same browser - Same Opportunity record - just login users are different

For AA >> I close the opp - reopen - CLOSE OPPORTUNITY button appears again - click on CLOSE button work fine

For BB >> I close the opp - reopen - CLOSE OPPORTUNITY button appears again - click on CLOSE button but not working.

I debugg my js code behind CLOSE OPP button - `Xrm.Page.data.getIsValid()` return true for user AA

I debugg my js code behind CLOSE OPP button - `Xrm.Page.data.getIsValid()` return false for user BB

In case of user BB, if i manually refresh form then every thing works normal.

```
function closeOpportunity(){
   -------------------
 if (!Xrm.Page.data.getIsValid()) return;
   -------------------
   OpenPopup();
}
```

**When I reopen my opportunity then Close Opp button appears in the commandbar/ribbon, when i click Close Opp button it calls a function where `Xrm.Page.data.getIsValid()` return different value for login user AA and login user BB.**

1. Following line of code return true for user AA and return false for user BB

   Xrm.Page.data.getIsValid()

   Why?
2. If i refresh my webpage by clicking on refresh icon in the browser window then `Xrm.Page.data.getIsValid()` also return true for user BB

Please help

Comment: We need more code than that. Do you have a jsbin?

Comment: seems you are returning abruptly from the code that is breaking the sequence. Check for js console errors as well.

Comment: @Vijay There is no console error.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What happens ? What *should* happen instead ?